# How do I troubleshoot this AWS SSH Configuration and Setup git error

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I had previously setup AWS ssh connection successfully using these [step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-windows.html) but recently I did the same for github on the same device. Now assuming thats why when I tried to connect again today (to AWS) and clone a repo, I got this error even after creating another key. Run this -> `$ ssh git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

And got this:
`Unable to negotiate with 52.94.226.180 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa`

I run `$ ssh -v git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

and got this

`OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021`

`debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config`

`debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com`

`debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

`debug1: Connecting to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [52.74.220.29] port 02.`

`debug1: Connection established.`

`debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/codecommit_rsa type 0`

`debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/codecommit_rsa-cert type -1`

`debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8`

`debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version AWSCodeCommit TW9uLCAxMyBEZWMgMjAyMSAxNDoTmPZk73EB+4R5600dPED9s6hW+11`

`debug1: compat_banner: no match: AWSCodeCommit TWDAwMI5/2x2e4YBq1PzJSUTmPZk73EB+4R5600dPED9s6hW+1ZWlIeHgzaW1QdDR5VnM0UXlnN0tENlNvSXUyeFZkbmFwd3c9`

`debug1: Authenticating to git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'APKAR4C3VQF'`

`debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory`

`debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory`

`debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory`

`debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent`

`debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received`

`debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256`

`debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)`

`Unable to negotiate with 52.74.220.29 port 02: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa` 
Could I be missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Unable+to+negotiate+no+matching+host+key+type+found.+Their+offer%3A+ssh-rsa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72804021/6064025